# Changing Preprocessor Directives C++

Tags: c++, using-directives

So I am trying to use a really old library (last updated in 1999) that performs numerical integration over two-dimensional regions using cubature rules. The problem I'm encountering is that every single file in the library (both headers and source files, so probably 40 or more files) uses

```
#include <headerfile.h>
```

Instead of using

```
#include "headerfile.h"
```

Furthermore, it just uses

```
cout << "Whatever it is you want to print"
```

Instead of

```
std::cout << "Things for printing"
```

And finally when importing all the c++ standard library files it uses

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

Instead

```
#include <iostream>
```

Does anybody know of a convenient and efficient way of going through each file and changing this? Maybe some sort of shell script or something? I really do not want to go through all these files by hand. While we're on the topic, does anyone know of a good numerical integration package that isn't so ancient and integrates over any two-dimensional shape? I'm using this one because it handles integration over oddly shaped regions really well, and if I can get it to compile it will be perfect for my purposes. I looked at CUBA but their integration methods only integrate over the unit hypercube, and I need to integrate over triangles and rectangles and all sorts of strange shapes.

Thanks!!

Comment: This sounds like simple trivial search and replace could do, google "search and replace multiple files" or such should give multiple options based on your operating system and environment.

Comment: "While we're on the topic, does anyone know of..."  Two things: Stack Overflow is not for asking for outside resources; Stack Overflow questions should be about one thing only (to the extent possible).

Comment: If this is a library that you have full control over, you can make a backup then do a search-and-replace (possibly with regular expressions) over all the files. A proper code editor would make this problem relatively trivial.

Comment: I am not sure if #include<iostream.h> would do anything. For cout, just add this after the include (using std::cout;). It does the same thing as changing it to std::cout, but only uses one line.